# How can I plot Charts w/ time x axis from JSON and MySQL in Chart.JS?

Tags: javascript, html, json, chart.js

I'd like to plot some charts using Chart.js.

I have a script that gets two arrays from a database in JSON format.

The two arrays are:
-An array of Temperature (float)
-An array of Time (Obtained by the Database at the moment in which a temperature enters it by means of the function Current_Timestamp ())

I'd like to be able to graph the temperatures depending on the date with Chart.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost/js/data.php",
    type: "GET",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var datos = {
            VectorTemp : [],
            VectorFecha : []
        }
        var len = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i<len;i++){
            if (data[i].chipID == 1){
                datos.VectorTemp.push(data[i].temp);
                datos.VectorFecha.push(data[i].fecha);
            }
        }

        console.log(datos);

        var ctx = $("#line-chartcanvas");
        var data = {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [
                {
                    x: datos.VectorFecha[1],
                    y: datos.VectorTemp[1]
                }
            ]
        };

        var options = {
            responsive: true,
            title:      {
                display: true,
                text:    "Chart.js Time Scale"
            },

        }

        var chart = new Chart (ctx, {
            type: "line",
            data : data,
            options: options

        });
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },

  });

});
```